# Outlook Add-in Pinned Timeout

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Good day, I have a custom outlook add-in, works beautifully but when i pinned the outlook add-in and left it pinned for couple of hours. The add in will be timeout. like blank page

Do we have some configuration on this thing?